# Menu options in eclipse are disable

Tags: eclipse

Options in the eclipse menu drop down are disabled like shown below.

[image]

Couldn't find a way to enable them. Is there any way other than using new eclipse instance.

Comment: See https://www.eclipse.org/org/press-release/20170925criticalbug.php

Comment: After restarting didn't work. Tried mentioned steps in the link, re-installing, changing the workspace. Nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MacOS High Sierra 13.1 , this workaround works. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=520176#c152

```
1. Find java.home used by your Eclipse (look for java.home in "About Eclipse" > "Installation Details" > "Configuration")

2. If your java.home is, for example, /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre , go to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home and create the subfolders Resources/English.lproj

3. Copy the DefaultApp.nib file from a 10.13 or older Mac to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/Resources/English.lproj (DefaultApp.nib can be found under /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/en.lproj or /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/English.lproj on Mac OS version < 10.13.1)
```

For the macos versions before 10.13.1, https://www.eclipse.org/org/press-release/20170925criticalbug.php this should work

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue can be solved with the following:

1. Quit eclipse.
2. Open your Terminal.
3. Navigate to Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS (`cd Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS`).
4. Run `./eclipse -nl en`.
5. Update to Eclipse Oxygen.1a ([where this bug is fixed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=520176)): *Help > Check for Updates*.

See also Eclipse announcement: *[Special Notice for Eclipse IDE Users on macOS 10.13 in non-English mode](https://www.eclipse.org/org/press-release/20170925criticalbug.php)* (which was written before Oxygen.1a was released)

Comment: ... 5. Update to Eclipse Oxygen.1a ([where this bug is fixed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=520176)).

Comment: After restarting didn't work. Tried mentioned steps in the link, re-installing, changing the workspace. Nothing helped.

Comment: Try to start Eclipse with the option `-clean`. Does `-nl en` work? What do exactly mean by _re-installed_ (uninstalled + installed of package X of version Y?) and by _changing the workspace_ (new workspace via `-data`?)?

Comment: @howlger when i say re-installed, removed version 4.7.1 and installed 4.7.1a. Changed the workspace folder. `-nl en` didn't work. Let me try `-clean` option.

Comment: looks like there is dependency on another defect. [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=522690)